# An error has occured. See the log file, eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.log

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-oxygen

I downloaded eclipse oxygen for macOS. Here is the link for reference:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/3a/eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg

I opened up  and launched eclipse once it was downloaded and an error came up telling me to see a log file. I'm pretty new at this so I have no idea what happened.

Previously I downloaded this:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

but I deleted it and installed eclipse oxygen. I am using a mac. Is there a way to fix this? If so how can I?

Comment: If you were prompted for a workspace location, it will be in there, in the hidden `.metadata` directory as the file named `.log`. Before that, though, Oxygen is not the current release, it's 2017's, and not really compatible with modern macOS and Java. You want to download the current one from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers .

Comment: @nitind Thank you. So, I have to delete eclipse then download the current one?

Comment: Yes, that's the most straightforward thing to getting it working.

Comment: @nitind Thank you so much! It worked! Do you also happen to know the latest link to download e(fx)clipse on it?

Comment: Unfortunately not something I have experience with, but it does look like they haven't had a release in three years. It might be installable using https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12 , from the Help menu.

Comment: @nitind No problem! Thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted eclipse and downloaded the newer version:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers